# Why isn't a background picture found XAMPP?

Tags: css, xampp

```
body {
  background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);      
  background-position: center center;      
  background-repeat: no-repeat;      
  background-attachment: fixed;      
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

For some reason I'm getting this error:

> GET http://localhost/images/background.jpg 404 (Not Found)

And also I'm kind of confused why the link is http://localhost/images/background.jpg instead of http://localhost/[project_name]/images/background.jpg

Comment: Why did you use a `/` at the beginning of the path if you didn't want to use the base directory of your document root?

Comment: In a css file, the image is relative to the css dir, so the image should be in css/images/background.jpg

Comment: Thank you all. You gave me the direction to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. I don't need to write '/' at the beginning of the path
2. I need to go up on 1 level in catalog because I'm in css folder

So the path should look like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
```